# How to record a breakpoint in SWTBot record

Tags: testing, eclipse-plugin, automated-tests, junit4, swtbot

I have a problem , when i try to put a breakpoint on debug mode and i record with "swtBot Test Recorder" the generated code is  :

```
bot.contextMenu("Add Breakpoint...").click();
bot.textWithLabel("Line number: ").setText("58");
bot.button("OK").click();
```

(i pressed right click on the field near line number column and select Add Breakpoint)
But when i put this code in my @Test it's wrong. I need a way to put a breakpoint on a specific line.

Comment: You'll need to give details about what you mean by "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

This works for Linux, i don't know about Windows:

```
bot.menu("Navigate").menu("Go to Line...").click();
bot.text().setText(breakpointString);
bot.button("OK").click();
bot.menu("Run").menu("Toggle Line Breakpoint").click();
```